# Decomposition of the space of Radon measures with respect fractional harmonic capacity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

It is well know that there is a generalization of Lebesgue decomposition theorem in the following way:

> Any non negative Radon measure can be decomposed uniquely into the sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular term with respect to the harmonic capacity. The absolute continuous term itself can be decomposed (not uniquely) to a function in $L^1$ and a function in $H^{-1}$ (dual of $H_0^1$).

I will be thankful to any one that will help me answering the following question:
 **do there exist such kind of decomposition involving the fractional harmonic capacity?**